# Avoid updating all textareas on keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this form:

http://jsfiddle.net/uS898/

```
<input type="text" name="firstTarget" />
<input type="text" name="secondTarget" />
<input type="text" name="thirdTarget" />
<textarea name="result">I have this text and I want to update it using firstTarget. After that I want to use secondTarget and thirdTarget</textarea>
<textarea name="result">I only want to use secondTarget here</textarea>
<textarea name="result">I only want to use thirdTarget here</textarea>
```

and this jquery

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
    var regVal=$(this).data('replace');    
   var newText=$('textarea').val().replace( regVal, this.value);   
    $(this).data('replace', this.value)     
    $('textarea').val(newText);    
}).each(function(){
    $(this).data('replace', this.name); 
})
```

When I fill out firstTarget input, it replaces the word "fistTarget" with the words that are written in the firstTarget input. 
Somehow, my code resets all the second and the third textareas when something is written in inputs.
I dont't want to reset the content from textarea 2 or textarea 3.
What can I do?

Comment: Your HTML markup is wrong. You have to organize it better.

Comment: Sorry about that... I fixed it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see my Example here: **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/EGEbuyeY/6/edit)**

```
var delay = 1000;
var wait = (function(){
 var timer = 0;
 return function(callback, ms){
 clearTimeout (timer);
 timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
};
})();

$('input').keyup(function(){
 var regVal=$(this).data('replace'); 
 var that = $(this);
 wait(function(){
   $('textarea').each(function(){
   var newText = $(this).val().replace( regVal, that.val());
   $(this).val(newText); 
  });
  }, delay);
 }).each(function(){
    $(this).data('replace', this.name);
 });
```

Comment: This does not work. It keeps only one input replacement on each input :)

Comment: Tell  me exactly what you want. Your question is not too clear.

Comment: I want all textareas to update with all input values, not only one, according to your example :)

Comment: Do you want to overwrite the text in the textarea with whatever you type in?

Comment: No.... We have 3 or more inputs. When this inputs are filled, they replace the words from textareas (that have different words in them). The bug that I want to fix is: when you write something on an input, it resets all textareas... and I don't want that.

Comment: Ok try this, if that's it I will update my answer.  http://jsbin.com/EGEbuyeY/2/edit

Comment: This kinda works, but needs to update also "secondTarget and thirdTarget" from the first textarea. We have 3 inputs/words in the first textarea.

Comment: Ahh ok. one min, let me take a look.

Comment: OK I think this is it. try this one and I will update my answer:  http://jsbin.com/EGEbuyeY/4/edit

Comment: Sorry.. there is a problem! You if you have a space inside the inputs, that messes it all up... It won't display any letters after it...

Comment: In fact.. it only works for values such as "111111111111111" - like same letter or number...

Comment: Why don't u do this on change event vs key up.

Comment: Just replace key up with change

Comment: @Mariuta Mihai Dan: I have updated my answer, and the DEMO(above). You need to put a delay between keyup and the time before you start updating the textarea. Otherwise the text such as "firstTarget" gets updated on first keyup and the next time around that text is not there anymore. Hence nothing to update. You could also achieve the same effect by firing this on change vs on keyup. Because then the function fires when the inputbox loses focus and the value have been changed. If you find this useful and this solves your problem, could you upbump my answer? Thanks

Comment: Yes it does, just wait one sec. You can change the delay time if you want.

Comment: Textarea does not update on several input update.. eg: when adding or removing words

Answer (score 0):

Either I'm misunderstanding your objective, or you may be overcomplicating things.  If you're just trying to tie each input to a textarea, this is all you need:

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
    var target_id = $(this).data('target');
    $('#' + target_id).val(this.value);
});
```

of course you have to update some attributes as follows:

```
 <input type="text" data-target="firstTarget" />
    <input type="text" data-target="secondTarget" />
    <input type="text" data-target="thirdTarget" />
    <textarea style="width:500px; height: 100px;" id="firstTarget">I have this text and I want to update it using firstTarget. After that I want to use secondTarget and thirdTarget</textarea>
<textarea style="width:500px; height: 100px;" id="secondTarget">I only want to use secondTarget here</textarea>
<textarea style="width:500px; height: 100px;" id="thirdTarget">I only want to use thirdTarget here</textarea>
```

Here's the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/C3rtg/4/).

Answer (score 0):

How about this: http://jsfiddle.net/DP4a8/1/ ?

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
    var input = this;
    var regVal=$(this).data('replace');    
    $('textarea').each(function() {
      var newText = this.value.replace(regVal, input.value);
      $(this).val(newText);
    });
    $(this).data('replace', this.value)     
}).each(function(){
    $(this).data('replace', this.name); 
})
```